# Programmatically find the installed version of pywin32

Tags: python, version, pywin32

Some Python packages provide a way for a program to get the installed version. E.g.

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.version.version
'1.5.0'
```

But I can't find a way to do so for [`pywin32`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/). What good way might there be to find out?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found a blog post ["Include version information in your Python packages" by Jean-Paul Calderone](http://as.ynchrono.us/2010/03/include-version-information-in-your_03.html) which showed you can get the version of `pywin32` this way:

```
>>> import win32api
>>> fixed_file_info = win32api.GetFileVersionInfo(win32api.__file__, '\\')
>>> fixed_file_info['FileVersionLS'] >> 16
212
```

Comment: Still working as of March 2022 with `pywin32` version 303

Answer (score 8):

Adapted from Mark's official response at: http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/2010-April/010404.html

```
import os
import distutils.sysconfig

pth = distutils.sysconfig.get_python_lib(plat_specific=1)
ver = open(os.path.join(pth, "pywin32.version.txt")).read().strip()
```

as Craig's answer no longer worked for me on the amd64 build.

Answer (score 4):

This is the only way I've figured out so far. It finds a file called `pywin32.version.txt` in the Python installation's `site-packages` directory, and reads the contents.

```
def get_pywin32_version():
    for path in sys.path:
        if os.path.isdir(path):
            filename = os.path.join(path, 'pywin32.version.txt')
            if os.path.isfile(filename):
                with open(filename) as f:
                    pywin32_version = f.read()
                pywin32_version = pywin32_version.strip()
                return pywin32_version
```

That's far from an official API, though! I don't know what versions of `pywin32` have installed that `pywin32.version.txt` file, and how likely that is to continue in future.